# HTML Mail linked image not showing in IOS Mail App

Tags: html, image, email, html-email

Hello guys I ran into a HTML Mail problem. I created a HTML Email Template which I am using for my app. Now the problem is that when linking the image from my server it does show the image on gmails WebClient but does not show it in the IOS Mail-App.

When linking any other image which I know from other Mails it does work though. So I would guess it has something to do with my server host.

I do have an SSL certificate and it responses with *200* or with *304*.

So when using

```html
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_74x24dp.png" alt="Logo" />
```

it will show on all devices but when using

```html
<img src="https://my.domain.com/my_logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

it will not show on IOS Mail-App.

I looked for alternatives but they all suffer the problem of E-Mail size.

Does IOS have a whitelist or something like that where you have to get into or do I miss a Response Header on my website. Maybe a faulty SSL-Certificate?

Comment: It should just work. Is your server listed on a blocklist somewhere, like for spam? Is there a CORS issue, perhaps--although I do know Apple ignore that for fonts, so shouldn't be.

Comment: @Nathan Thats what I was thinking. It should jsut work. I guess it coudl actually be that its blocked due to spam. I send alot of mails to myself for testing. Any idea how to fix that? But does it make sense that it block that one image url but all others not? My server should not be blacklisted cuz its just a dev server. I realy have no plan at that point. Also tried different image hosts but not one worked.

Comment: If yo;u always open your tests and/or click on the links, it should have a pretty good reputation. But if it's just one image and others on the same server work, then the only thing I can think of is the image itself is corrupt (but it works on gmail, so, I guess not?) or the image itself is blacklisted. Perhaps try changing the image slightly, or resaving, and see if that works.

Comment: Shouldnt be an issue with the image because i tried different once already but I will give it another try at the weekend. The images that worked where just litterly from the URL which I foudn them from. Will try if something like wikipedia and so on works and it may rly just be my server. Thx for the ideas